# secrets client of azure sdk for go returns empty secret even if rbac is set correctly (managed identity)

Tags: azure, go, azure-managed-identity, secret-key, azure-container-apps

the response of the Get fkt of the secrets client from go azure sdk
("github.com/Azure/azure-sdk-for-go/sdk/resourcemanager/keyvault/armkeyvault")
returns an valid instance of
resp of type SecretsClientGetResponse,
but the property resp.Secret.Properties.Value is Null.
there i expect the wanted secret value.

i use the azure sdk from
"github.com/Azure/azure-sdk-for-go/sdk/resourcemanager/keyvault/armkeyvault"
in a container app with default credentials
-> env var AZURE_CLIENT_ID is set to corresponding managed identity client id
-> managed identity has "secrets user" access rights over the corresponding key vault
-> furthermore the managed identity has the requesting app as assigned ressource

i don't can find more specifications which must be set but it still dont works to get the content of a secret from the key vault

can anybody help?